# I am not able to fetch single record from access database in C#.Net

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I am doing project on Library Management System. I want to fetch the all data about the student using the borrower number by select query. But my Code is not working Its giving some exception as type mismatch in criteria expression at line number 40 dAdapter.Fill(dataTable);. Please Help Me. Here is my Code.
THANK YOU :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace LibraryManagment
{
public partial class ViewStudent : Form
{
    private OleDbConnection bookConn;
    private OleDbCommand oleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand();
    //parameter from mdsaputra.udl
    private String connParam = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\mini\database\library.mdb;Persist Security Info=False";



    public ViewStudent()
    {
        bookConn = new OleDbConnection(connParam);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();

        OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Student where BorrowerNo = '"+ this.txtBorrowerNo.Text +"';", connParam);
        OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter);

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        dAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

        for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dataTable.Rows[i][0], dataTable.Rows[i][1], dataTable.Rows[i][2], dataTable.Rows[i][3], dataTable.Rows[i][4], dataTable.Rows[i][5], dataTable.Rows[i][6], dataTable.Rows[i][7]);
        }
    }


        private void ViewStudent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'libraryDataSet.Student' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
           // this.studentTableAdapter4.Fill(this.libraryDataSet.Student);

        }


}
```

}

Comment: Please be more specific than "giving some exception." We cannot assist you without knowing what is failing.

Comment: Do you forget to open bookConn before fetching data?

Comment: You are complicating a simple operation. Read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: exception as type mismatch in criteria expression at line number 40 dAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

Comment: What is the datatype of borrowerno in your database?

Comment: its Number datatype in my access database. and I've tried to typecast the textbox value to the integer value but the problem still remaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error mentioned in your comments, the borrower no is of type number and that seems to be causing the problem.

```
OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Student where BorrowerNo = "+ this.txtBorrowerNo.Text +";", connParam);
```

Notice that I have removed the single quotes. You use the single quotes when your data type is string.